# column are full width in IE 8 - Css bootstrap

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3.0.3 in my web page and add html5shiv lib and respond lib for fix it this but it is not worked on internet explorer 8.

my html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:red;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:green;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:blue;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Its worked good in FF and Webkits browsers but result in IE :

[image]

Now demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LaN3d/6/), how can I fix it?

Comment: i also able to duplicate your issue. http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/LaN3d/4/ fullscreen: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/LaN3d/4/show/ . You have done one mistake. you have nested container inside row which should be vice-versa. I also corrected the respond.js path.

Comment: @Ravimallya Nop it isn't duplicate, Your fixed sample is not worked on IE-8.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on the solution in the thread : [Must Bootstrap container elements include row elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994012/twitter-bootstrap-must-container-contain-row), your markup should be :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:red;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:green;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background:blue;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use this CSS to achieve it in IE8:

```
.container
{
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

.row
{
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.col-sm-4
{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

here is the working  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LaN3d/7/)

The `.row` class is not required inside a `.container`, but if you include then, **container > row is the order not row > container** (*which you code*)!

**EDIT**

It might be worth noting that [`respond.js`](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) only works for local files. So if you have got `css` files of bootstrap from CDN for your website on IE8, it won't work, instead, try with a local copy of `bootstrap.css`

> **Internet Explorer 8 and Respond.js**
>
> Beware of the following caveats when using Respond.js in your
> development and production environments for Internet Explorer 8.
>
> **Respond.js and cross-domain CSS**
> Using Respond.js with CSS hosted on a different (sub)domain (for
> example, on a CDN) requires some additional setup. See the Respond.js
> docs for details.
>
> **Respond.js and file://**
> Due to browser security rules, Respond.js doesn't work with pages
> viewed via the file:// protocol (like when opening a local HTML file).
> To test responsive features in IE8, view your pages over HTTP(S). See
> the Respond.js docs for details.
>
> **Respond.js and @import**
> Respond.js doesn't work with CSS that's referenced via @import. In
> particular, some Drupal configurations are known to use @import. See
> the Respond.js docs for details.
>
> **IE Compatibility modes**
> Bootstrap is not supported in the old Internet Explorer compatibility
> modes. To be sure you're using the latest rendering mode for IE,
> consider including the appropriate  tag in your pages:

Source : [**Getbootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers)

Answer (score 4):

If "responsiveness" is not required, you can use col-xs-* classes instead of setting up proxy for respond.js. It works, because col-xs-* classes are media-agnostic. It solved the issue in my case.

Comment: Using col-xs-* fixed this issue for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to apply this in a way that would only apply to IE and not any other browsers as it can break some of your responsive web sites. This page speaks specifically to how to apply IE only CSS.

[Apply CSS rules if browser is IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541982/apply-css-rules-if-browser-is-ie)

Answer (score 1):

Addition you need remember that bootstrap.css is above respond.js in your head section:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Mobile viewport optimisation -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap example</title>

    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/noscript.css" />
    </noscript>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../assets/bootstrap-3.3.5/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script src="../assets/js/ie/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/ie/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```