# Can I have a Bootstrap col inside of another col?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am still new to Bootstrap and I am trying to figure out what is correct and what is not. Is it acceptable to have a `col` inside of a `col`? In the example below, I have a form that I want to fit half of the screen. I also want certain form-control elements to be half size while other of full width. Would this be the correct way to go about this or is there a better way?

Example code:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="website">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg pull-right col-xs-12">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, that's OK to have, according to Bootstrap's [Grid Template](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) guide:

> Two columns with two nested columns
> --
>
> Per the documentation, nesting is easy—just put a row of columns within an existing column. This gives you two columns starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops, with another two (equal widths) within the larger column.
>
> At mobile device sizes, tablets and down, these columns and their nested columns will stack.

However, there is a point to a Bootstrap `.row`, which is to apply a negative margin in order to align content. If you don't mind gutters, or are capable of adjusting the columns yourself to account for this, then there's no point in adding a `.row` container for your nested columns. You can put a .row class on the same element as `.col` to remove these gutters, as well (thanks to [Extragory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680521/extragorey) for pointing that out).

Likewise, not wrapping a column in a row will result in certain properties not applying correctly like the `flex` properties on the `.col` class. `.row` has `display: flex`, which is required for any children with flex properties to apply those properties... otherwise they will get ignored.

Comment: @ChristianJuth No worries. Some further reading that might be helpful: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/ and http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/

Comment: From bootstrap site
"Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows."

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Comment: @baligena Yes, only columns may be immediate children of rows, but rows can be immediate children of columns, too.

Comment: No it´s not OK. You can nest columns inside columns as long as those nested columns "live" inside a row. In fact, if you check the html behind that very example on Bootstrap documentation you will see that those nested columns are in fact placed inside a row. Go on, follow the link given in the answer, right click on the columns and Inspect Element.

Comment: @Rodrigo As the big quote in my answer says, "**put a row** of columns inside an existing column".

Comment: @Rodrigo also see [my comment below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710013/can-i-have-a-bootstrap-col-inside-of-another-col/29710073?noredirect=1#comment47556736_29710235); columns don't *need* to be within a row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994012/must-bootstrap-container-elements-include-row-elements

Comment: -1. The answer is misleading. In the code provided, the OP is nesting columns inside other columns without any row in the middle. Your answer states that you can include a **row of colums**, not columns directly.

Comment: @David That's incorrect, you're inferring what was not implied by the Bootstrap documentation. "A row of columns" here just refers to a group or collection of columns, not an actual `row` class. See https://jsfiddle.net/6L2Lcapd/ to demonstrate columns nested directly within other columns.

Comment: @David I'd also suggest you read my comments above as well as my comments on mistykristie's answer specifying exactly that ("columns don't **have** to be in a row")

Comment: I don't agree. I read all the comments and I stand by what I said.. The [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting) are pretty clear about nesting: it doesn't say "add a row", it says "add a `.row`", so it is referring nothing but a class. In your fiddle, the cols are not reaching the sides of the row and that is not the expected behaviour. Of course, you can put a container inside a row and the row inside a column, you can apply css classes as you want, but it is not the intended structure of Bootstrap and you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @David Yes, and OP simply asked if it would work fine, which it does; he also asks for 'better ways', so feel free to add a different answer if you have another way to solve OP's problem.

Comment: @David However, I will add a blurb about the function of the .row container, because that is useful for painting a complete picture, despite not being required for `.col`s to work.

Comment: You can also put the `.row` class on the same element as the `.col-` class(es) to remove the gutters.

Answer (score 20):

You can have columns nested as many levels deep as you'd like, but they should generally be inside a row. The rows have negative margins to account for the padding on the columns, so if you have columns nested inside columns without a row in between, it will mess up the alignment of your page.

Comment: But you added a `.row` to on input without applying it to the other inputs. That is why the sizing is weird.

Comment: You stepped back with no reason. Columns must be in a row (for the reason you have explained) according any example and reference in the docs. In the [same link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting) that TylerH has provided you can read: "Nesting columns: To nest your content with the default grid, add a new .row and set of .col-sm-* columns within an existing .col-sm-* column". This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @David Wrong; please read and consider *all* the commentary before making such claims. The most relevant link for to read is the one saying "columns don't *need* to be within a row". Seeing the proof and ignoring it is one thing, but arguing that others must ignore it is harmful and disingenuous. Not to mention the Bootstrap documentation doesn't specify they *must* be children of rows.

Comment: @TylerH I read all the comments. From the link you provided: "The bootstrap grid is composed of 12 columns that can be adjusted in any combination **within a row**" and "the .row container has a separate task and is there (**and required**) to readjust the last grid columns gutter width". You didn't provide any new argument so I stand by what I said. And, regarding my comment being "harmful and disingenuous", well, I can just wish you a nice day and encourage you to use Bootstrap as you consider convenient: at the end, is just code, not a matter of live or death.

Answer (score -1):

```
<section class="options pt-3 pb-5" id="options">
    <div class="container pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="options_title text-start pt-5 pb-2">
                    <h2 class="pt-5 pb-2">Crafted for Startup, SaaS <br> and Business Sites.</h2>
                    <p class="options_p pt-1 pb-5">The main ‘thrust’ is to focus on educating attendees on how to <br> best
                        protect highly
                        vulnerable business applications with <br> interactive panel discussions and roundtables.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="options_check d-flex justify-content-start align-items-start text-start">
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-start">
                        <p class="check_fai"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> Premium quality</p>
                        <p class="check_fai"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> No code required</p>
                        <p class="check_fai"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> Use for lifetime</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-start">
                        <p class="check_fai"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> Regular updates</p>
                        <p class="check_fai"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> Rich document</p>
                        <p class="check_fai"><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i> Developer friendly</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 pt-5">
                <img src="img/options-image.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```